# how to check whether a phone number is a Cuba number or US domestic number

Tags: java, parsing

I found that both CUBA and US phone numbers are 10 digits. So when we met a number in 10 digits, how do we know it is a CUBA number or US phone number?

Comment: I don't think you can without the country code part of the number. And/or it's assumed to be the same country as the person making the call if it doesn't have a country code.

Comment: By requiring one (or both) to include the country code. For the US it's `1` and for Cuba it's `53`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, [Cuban telephone numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Cuba) are 8-digits, US 10-digits. You might also want to read about the [North American Numbering Plan (NANP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan) as that may also be of use when trying to parse US phone numbers.